# What is this error when trying to install ATI video driver?

Tags: drivers, video, ati

When trying to install the driver the following error message occurs

`Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version
default:v2:i686:lib::none:3.0.0-15-generic; make sure that the version is being
correctly set by --iscurrentdistro`

This was given when using "Uncompressing ATI Proprietary Linux Driver-8.593" in a terminal

I have an IBM Thinkpad T42 and no video driver is loaded since I installed Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the video card ATI Mobility Radeon 9600 in your T42 is no longer supported by AMD.

[Reference](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/737-28041SupportforATIMobility.aspx)

This information is also available on the ATI wiki page:

> ATI/AMD dropped Catalyst support for these cards in Catalyst 9-4.
>   These cards are supported with the legacy ATI 9-3 Catalyst release,
>   but you MUST use a kernel 2.6.28 (or earlier) and Xserver 1.5 (or
>   earlier). For example, you can use Catalyst 9-3 if you're running
>   Ubuntu 8.04 or Debian Lenny/5.0. Open source support is good and 3D is
>   still improving.

[Reference](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware)

Your only option with 11.10 is to use the open source driver by default.